# web view did finish load labelname.hidden = yes not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am very new to iOS programming and am making a simple app. the first UITabBarItem loads a page but before it loads there is a label. I am trying to make the label disappear after the web page loads but it doesn't work. I believe I need to set the web view delegate but I don't know how.

firstcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OTFFirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webPage;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pageLoading;

@end
```

firstcontroller.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://asdf.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webPage loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webPage
{
    _pageLoading.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Why do so many posts start "I am new to..."? At least, speaking for myself I've come find it tiresome and irrelevant to any question. It's also usually implicit one way or another.

Comment: sorry its just so they understand im not experienced..?

Comment: in your nib, have you connected the webview delegate to the owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `_webPage.delegate = self;` before calling `loadRequest:`.
You should alse modify interface definition to `@interface OTFFirstViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>`.

Comment: @OP since you are using IBOutlets, just set the connect the delegate to the owner. You'll save a line of code :)

Comment: I have no idea what that means. sorry.